# I have a dataset where the columns are in int format but when I do data.columns.dtype it shows me dtype('O'). How can I change this to int?

Tags: python, dataframe

As you can see the results of the code data.dtypes still indicates 'O', which is Object while all the other columns are in INT.

```
Frequency_of_Isssuance_Statements     int8
Type of Card Issued                   int8
Region                                int8
Average_Salary                       int64
Loan Amount                          int64
Duration_of_Loan                     int64
Monthly_Payments                     int64
Status_of_Paying_Off_The_Loan         int8
Characterization_of_Payment           int8
dtype: object
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html): *Columns with mixed types are stored with the object dtype*. See more information about [`dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dtypes). As your columns have different types, the general type has to be `object`

Comment: thank you Tomerikoo. So basically thereis  no way to change this "dtype"object" to INT or float?

Comment: I guess not, but why does it bother you? And actually there is, if you make all your columns be of the same `int` type, for example `int64`

Comment: the reason is because I'm trying to plot that data using pair plot on Jupyter Notebook. But for some reason I keep getting this error --                           
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\nonparametric\kde.py in kdensityfft(X, kernel, bw, weights, gridsize, adjust, clip, cut, retgrid)
    450     try:
--> 451         bw = float(bw)
    452     except:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'scott'

Comment: Seems unrelated to your current question... Apparently you have a string value which is unexpected. You might want to better understand your problem and formulate the question more accurately

Comment: Sorry about that. I actually formulated the question clearly on another question prompt. I would be grateful for your help. Here's the link. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63928270/10324233